# store save and show members contacts with google maps api in grails application

Tags: grails, plugins, location, maps

I need to store, save and show members contact address details on the grails application.
can somebody please help me guide in the right direction please.

My grails app has spring security plugin to take care of user authorisation and contact details are stored on separate to table.

I also want to store all the addresses a user has ever put in the database and show it all on on maps at once.

Can it simply be done using google maps api? if yes please help me out bit more.. 
or do i need any google maps plugin for grails, if there is any?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a Grails controller that returns json and pass that to the google api or wherever you are creating marker locations on the map. No need for a plugin.